# fix while converting NSString to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, utf-8

I am getting `NSString * responseString` as below format which is already **utf8** encoded. Data is from webserver database.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"ID\":{\"Content\":\u0e09\u0e31\u0e19\u0e23\u0e31\u0e01\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13,\"type\":\"text\"},\"ContractTemplateID\":{\"Content\":\u0e09\u0e31\u0e19\u0e23\u0e31\u0e01\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13,\"type\":\"text\"}}";

//Trying to convert to UTF 
    NSString *utf = [jsonString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//convert to data 
    NSData *data = [utf dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//trying to create NSDictionary JSON
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];


    NSLog(@"json: %@", son);
    NSLog(@"utf: %@", utf);
```

**I NEED TO CONVERT IT INTO NSDICTIONARY SO I CAN PARSE AND GET Value of *Content***

**Output Results:**

```
utf: (null)

utf: {"ID":{"Content":ฉันรักคุณ,"type":"text"},"ContractTemplateID":{"Content":ฉันรักคุณ,"type":"text"}}
```

Comment: just set it to your label and you should see, "काम","एक",,"शक्तिा".

Comment: please check edit part

Answer (score 2):

Strings will present as Unicode in debugger. Just show them with labels or convert into characters with some online tools.

Comment: @iphonemaclover You can try to print `[json valueForKey:@"data"] as! String`

Comment: print in label works but unable to convert it into dictionary so i can parse it